# The proof of $\Omega^k_G(P;V)\cong \Omega^k(M;P\times_G V)$.

Tags: reference-request, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ be a $G$-principal bundle and $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ a representation.

The space of $k$ forms on $M$ with values in $P\times_G V$ (denote as $\Omega^k(M;P\times_G V)$  can be identified with with the space of horizontal, right invariant $k$-forms on $M$ (denote as $\Omega^k_G(P;V))$.

Ie, there is an isomorphism:

$\Omega^k_G(P;V)\cong \Omega^k(M;P\times_G V)$.

Could you please give me the proof of this result or suggest me a reference where I can find the proof in details (since I found the proof in some lecture notes but it was not clear).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked out this link? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1184923/58951

Comment: Yes I did check it, but it wasn't clear for me!

Comment: Could you tell us which part of the proof that is not clear to you?